# Null Pointer Exception while calling a bean method (PrimesFaces)

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, nullpointerexception

the problem is that when i use my command button i have a NPE and i dont why there is some code and a stacktrace of the exception i hope you will help because i have spend a day and still dont know why (primefaces 4.0 ) JSF 2.1.6

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.el.ELException: /test.xhtml at line 54 and column 113 action="#{messageBean.save}": java.lang.NullPointerException
at           javax.faces.component._MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.invoke(_MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.java:96)
at    org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:100)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:120)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastAll(UIViewRoot.java:937)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:271)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1249)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:675)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:34)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:171)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: /test.xhtml at line 54 and column 113 action="#{messageBean.save}": java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:95)
at javax.faces.component._MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.invoke(_MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.java:88)
... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at ma.corporate.bean.MessageBean.save(MessageBean.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:273)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:83)
... 30 more
```

My Page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
<p:panel header="Contactez Nous">
    <p:growl id="message" showDetail="true"/>
        <h:form id="form">
            <p:panelGrid style="width:700px;" styleClass="contactcss"
                columns="2">
                <p:inputText value="#{messageBean.message.nomComplet}" style="width:600px" id="nom" required="true"
                    requiredMessage="Champs Obligatoire">
                    <p:watermark for="nom" value="Nom" />
                </p:inputText>
                <p:message for="nom" display="both" />


                <p:inputText style="width:600px" value="#{messageBean.message.email}" id="email" required="true"
                    requiredMessage="Champ Obligatoire"
                    validatorMessage="Email Invalide">
                    <p:watermark for="email" value="Email" />
                    <f:validateRegex
                        pattern="^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$" />
                </p:inputText>
                <p:message for="email" display="both" />


                <p:inputText style="width:600px" value="#{messageBean.message.objet}" id="objet" required="true"
                    requiredMessage="Champ Obligatoire">
                    <p:watermark for="objet" value="Objet" />
                </p:inputText>
                <p:message for="objet" display="both" />


                <p:inputMask mask="9999-999-999" style="width:600px" value="#{messageBean.message.telephone}" id="telephone">
                <p:watermark for="telephone" value="téléphone" />
                </p:inputMask>
                <p:message for="telephone" display="both" />


                <p:inputTextarea style="width:600px;height:200px" value="#{messageBean.message.textMessage}" id="message"
                    required="true" requiredMessage="Champ Obligatoire">
                    <p:watermark for="message" value="Message" />
                </p:inputTextarea>
                <p:message for="message" display="both" />


                <p:commandButton update=":form :message" style="float:right;" action="#{messageBean.save}" value="Envoyer"></p:commandButton>
            </p:panelGrid>

        </h:form>
        </p:panel>

</h:body>
</html>
```

My Bean
    package ma.corporate.bean;

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import ma.corporate.facade.MessageFacade;
import ma.corporate.model.Message;
import ma.corporate.util.Email;
import ma.corporate.util.EmailSender;

import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;

@ManagedBean(name = "messageBean")
@SessionScoped
public class MessageBean implements Serializable {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private MessageFacade messageFacade;
private List<Message> messages;
private Message message;
private Email email =new Email();
private String reponse;
public MessageBean() {

    message = new Message();
}

public List<Message> getMessages() {
    // messages = messageFacade.Lister();
    messageFacade = new MessageFacade();
    messages = messageFacade.Lister();
    return messages;
}

public void setMessages(List<Message> messages) {
    this.messages = messages;
}

public Message getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(Message message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public void save() {
    System.out.println(message.getEmail());
    System.out.println(message.getNomComplet());
    System.out.println(message.getObjet());
    System.out.println(message.getTelephone());
    System.out.println(message.getTextMessage());
    messageFacade.enregistrer(message);
}

public void Supprimer(Message message) {
    messageFacade.supprimer(message);
    messages = messageFacade.Lister();
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new    FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"Succès","Suppression Complète"));
}

public void init(Message message) {

    this.message = message;
    email.setDestinataire(message.getEmail());
    email.setObjet(message.getObjet());
    //email.setTexte("eljfdksjlfhdskjfsdhfkds");
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(":form1:dlg3");
    //System.out.println(this.message.getNomComplet());
}

public void sendEmail()
{
    /*System.out.println("Send Email");
    System.out.println(email.getObjet());
    System.out.println(email.getTexte());
    System.out.println(email.getDestinataire());*/
    //FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"En Cours","En Cours d'envoi"));

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    EmailSender sender = new EmailSender(email);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"Succès","Message Envoyé"));

    //System.out.println("après emailSender");
}

public Email getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(Email email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getReponse() {
    return reponse;
}

public void setReponse(String reponse) {
    this.reponse = reponse;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved my problem it was
 `messageFacade = new MessageFacade();` must be in the constructor and not in a the function `getMessages()`